# Cherry Tree Leaves

Tags: trees, cherries

I noticed today the out side perimeter of the cherry tree leaves are red is this a problem?
I've  had the cherry tree for two months and its in the ground here in sunny La Verne CA...

I have attached some pictures for you below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: More info please - what part of the world are  you in? How long have you had the cherry tree? Is it in the ground or in a pot and can you add a photo of the whole tree please

Comment: Bill, welcome! I see you are trying hard to get this posting thing to work. The trick is to use the [edit] link right under the question. Then  use the image icon and follow the pop-up menu. I will help for now, thanks for trying. Not all new users have the patience to learn how the site works. I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help] for a start.